# Get Diagnostic Information from returned Email through OLE Outlook

Tags: outlook, ole, diagnostics, guptateamdeveloper

How is it possible to get the diagnostic information from an email received in Outlook. We're using some ole thing in gupta/teamdeveloper. I want to find out if the email was returned by the system if the sender was not found because we're using the sent/received date and when that is empty (which apparently happens when the mail is returned by the system) our software crashes because the ole thing can't read the empty date...

Answer (score 1):

Use the Outlook_ReportItem object which is similar to a MailItem object, and it contains a report (usually the non-delivery report) or error message from the mail transport system.

If you don't have it in your automation apl already, then you'll need to re-generate the apl.
All the functions you need will be in the Functional Class once the interface has been (re) generated properly.

[image]